# Is it possible to wait for a condition in terraform test?

Tags: terraform

I trying out `terraform test` against my infrastructure. The system contains two S3 buckets, a Transfer Family SFTP server, an Eventbridge rule and a Lambda function. When deploy is finished, the Lambda will hit the SFTP and check for new files. With my setup, it will find a new file and upload into the second bucket. The function is triggered every minute using Eventbridge.

In the Terraform test, I'd like to verify that the S3 object exists - which can take up to a minute. Is there currently a way to write this test in HCL?

From what I have seen, you can use `data` elements in a `check`. The AWS provider 4.25.0 (unreleased) [will add](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.25.0/CHANGELOG.md) the possibility to set read timeouts on data sources. I assume this would be a way to model this assert. However, since the provider version is not available, is there any workaround that I can do for now?

Comment: "AWS provider 4.25.0 (unreleased)" This was released over 14 months ago on August 4, 2022. Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: You are right. I somehow got confused because it says Unreleased if you follow that link above. But yes, we are already at 5.x

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is built under the assumption that a provider will not return a result from its "apply change" operation until the object described in the desired state is in a "ready to use" state. When something has a separate waiting period after it's been created before it becomes usable then Terraform expects the provider itself to monitor the object and wait until it reaches the appropriate status before returning.

For that reason, there's no functionality in the Terraform language itself for "poll repeatedly until this operation is done". The expectation is that you'd make sure your output values depend on whatever resources need to be "ready to use" before returning, and then the provider itself will be the one to determine when the objects are actually ready.

Of course in your case things are a little more tricky because you're not waiting for a single object managed by a provider to become ready, but rather you're waiting for a bunch of different objects to collaborate together and produce some result.

As you've noticed, it would in principle be possible to use a provider which has a data source that essentially blocks until the background operation has completed and then optionally returns information about what was created. That could either be functionality offered in an existing provider, or functionality in a provider you write yourself specifically for this purpose.

I would also note that you seem to be trying to use `terraform test` to test something that I might classify as "application behavior" rather than testing infrastructure provisioning. The line between those two is of course a blurry one -- particularly when you're using systems like Lambda that abstract away the compute runtime details -- but if the behavior you want to test is mediated by some application code that's running in Lambda then `terraform test` might not be the best vehicle for that situation, since it's set up mainly for testing the behaviors of the Terraform module itself.

---

Aside from relying on specialized provider functionality that knows how to politely poll for the specific situation you're interested in, the only real alternative that comes to my mind is to use [the `hashicorp/time` provider's `time_sleep` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) to introduce an artificial delay after which the operation ought to have completed.

That solution is non-ideal in that it will always wait the same fixed time period and will not be able to complete faster if the underlying operation does. But in return, it's an option that doesn't require the provider to have any specific knowledge of your system.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your detailed answer. I think i'll try the `sleep` resource.